# Activerecord doen't release memory after build files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-management, rails-activerecord, rack-mini-profiler

I created a controller function for build a backup of database or some part of it, but after created the files e sent them, the allocated memory doesn't released.

The memory use report made with [rack-mini-profiler gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-mini-profiler/versions/0.10.1) show that the most part of memory is occupied by ActiveReccord and it doesn't released in the end. The full report is [here](https://mega.nz/#!NpMV0D4B!FNOpbUJUNo_LonHENmXpawPXPe4m_RMFh1prmsf6AXc).

Comment: Code for create file

File.open(zip_data_path, 'r') do |f|

    send_data f.read, type: 'application/zip', filename:"#{model_name}.zip"

end

File.delete(zip_data_path)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to reduce memory problems (Not completely resolved).

Write database intensive code in the block written as below.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  write your code here...
end
```

Also you can try running the garbage collector with `GC.start` in the end of action.

Let me know if this helps